# In Angularjs is there any scenario where is more recommended to use js native onClick events over ng-click directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have found this [angular challenges](http://www.jomendez.com/angularjs-mini-challenges/) serie of articules on internet, and I’m using some of these challenges as Interview questions for the process of hiring new AngularJs Developer.
Now for this particular one: "[Problem when using JS events in AngularJs.](http://www.jomendez.com/2015/05/05/mini-challenge-1-problem-js-events-angularjs/)", even thought when the author said “we recommend to use directives to handling events all the time”

1. Do you think there could be a scenario where we can’t use native angular directives to handle events?
2. From a technical perspective, does this particular challenge make any sense?
3. If so, is $timeout() the best approache to safely excecute the angular cycle digest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you need to use `directives` to handle DOM events because angular's directives will automatically trigger the `apply` function to detect whether a value has changed or not. But if you use either `jQuery` to `javascript` then you need to trigger `apply` function manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. The next grade above regular template directives are custom directives that manipulate the DOM.  First grade is using Angular. Second grade is being able to customize and extend it, as if you were extending the angular library itself.
2. Yes. I would hire developers who know the difference between the first grade and the second grade, and test their skills in both.
3. Use $scope.$apply to trigger a digest cycle - not $timeout

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Surely you can write your code in a function block and can bind it to some respective element which will be used as an event trigger. Event will get triggered and the function block will get executed as conditions meet.

Moreover its not recommended to do from a developers perspective as you have inbuilt directives that can be used directly instead writing your own code to perform the same. Also these already developed directives have been tested and are used by thousand of developers, using them in your code will minimize the chances of error in code.

Yes $timeout() can be used to execute the angular cycle digest, when you have to take performance factor into consideration.$timeout service only schedules a single call to the function so performance will not get affected.But if you are not bothered about performance ,like in some case you just have a little block of code then you can also use $digest [$digest always reevaluates specified block of code]. And if you need to reevaluate all watchers in available scope then $apply will be the best option.